# Cloudfare middleware recursively bypassess protection

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

i have installed cfscrape,and use it in my scrapy project to bypass cloudfare protection.It seems not working.I can add some more information about my code if necessary.I provide some code from settings.py:`

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25

DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language': 'en',
}
USER_AGENT_LIST = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like asdlkjqwdj) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 2.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like kqjwdqwd) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/123123.123',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like asdqwdqw) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7'
]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    # The priority of 560 is important, because we want this middleware to kick in just before the scrapy built-in `RetryMiddleware`.
     'scrapy_cloudflare_middleware.middlewares.CloudFlareMiddleware': 560,
     'binaaz.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
     'binaaz.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None
    # Disable compression middleware, so the actual HTML pages are cached
}
```

and here is output:

```
2019-01-18 15:02:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-01-18 15:02:59 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-01-18 15:02:59 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-01-18 15:03:00 [cloudflaremiddleware] DEBUG: Cloudflare protection detected on https://bina.az/items/all, trying to bypass...
2019-01-18 15:03:00 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): bina.az
2019-01-18 15:03:00 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /items/all HTTP/1.1" 503 None
2019-01-18 15:03:08 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Resetting dropped connection: bina.az
2019-01-18 15:03:09 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?jschl_vc=6d688f88cb5562fd00a5ee16689e26c9&pass=1547809384.962-1OiFgM1jrn&jschl_answer=18.089701993600002 HTTP/1.1" 302 159
2019-01-18 15:03:09 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /items/all HTTP/1.1" 503 None
2019-01-18 15:03:17 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Resetting dropped connection: bina.az
2019-01-18 15:03:17 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?jschl_vc=e719be7793db058c78b89dc24f6e39b7&pass=1547809393.639-gfrUEjO5oa&jschl_answer=26.1093884035 HTTP/1.1" 302 159
2019-01-18 15:03:17 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /items/all HTTP/1.1" 204 0
2019-01-18 15:03:17 [cloudflaremiddleware] DEBUG: Successfully bypassed the protection for https://bina.az/items/all, re-scheduling the request
2019-01-18 15:03:18 [cloudflaremiddleware] DEBUG: Cloudflare protection detected on https://bina.az/items/all, trying to bypass...
2019-01-18 15:03:18 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): bina.az
2019-01-18 15:03:18 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /items/all HTTP/1.1" 503 None
2019-01-18 15:03:26 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Resetting dropped connection: bina.az
2019-01-18 15:03:27 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?jschl_vc=faf6647605a0b45ed9958c055de11334&pass=1547809403.2-RdtkjUMCBv&jschl_answer=35.723157815600004 HTTP/1.1" 302 159
2019-01-18 15:03:27 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /items/all HTTP/1.1" 503 None
2019-01-18 15:03:35 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Resetting dropped connection: bina.az
2019-01-18 15:03:35 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?jschl_vc=8a0665b0b9df3707f15de0299d196b33&pass=1547809411.873-xrZecnfmeE&jschl_answer=-3.7878104051 HTTP/1.1" 302 159
2019-01-18 15:03:36 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /items/all HTTP/1.1" 204 0
2019-01-18 15:03:36 [cloudflaremiddleware] DEBUG: Successfully bypassed the protection for https://bina.az/items/all, re-scheduling the request
2019-01-18 15:03:36 [cloudflaremiddleware] DEBUG: Cloudflare protection detected on https://bina.az/items/all, trying to bypass...
2019-01-18 15:03:36 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): bina.az
2019-01-18 15:03:36 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /items/all HTTP/1.1" 503 None
2019-01-18 15:03:45 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Resetting dropped connection: bina.az
2019-01-18 15:03:45 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?jschl_vc=671d8f3bfcb227960607a55f33183748&pass=1547809421.422-h5xJraFbRf&jschl_answer=20.2767620475 HTTP/1.1" 302 159
2019-01-18 15:03:45 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://bina.az:443 "GET /items/all HTTP/1.1" 204 0
2019-01-18 15:03:45 [cloudflaremiddleware] DEBUG: Successfully bypassed the protection for https://bina.az/items/all, re-scheduling the request
```

P.S: I have updated cfscrape to latest version.

Comment: Have you considered opening a bug report at https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/issues ?

Comment: Okay man, i will